# Android- Blank White Space at bottom in Jquery Mobile/Phonegap App

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am developing a app in jquery mobile/phonegap for android. Problem is white space at the bottom of screen.Screenshot will help it better.I have searched on internet but couldn't find 
suitable answer.

Screenshot:
http://img248.imageshack.us/img248/5922/jquerymobile.png

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Slider Stop</title> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova-1.8.0.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.81.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

    </head> 
    <body>


        <div data-role="page" id="home">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>App</h1>
        </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <p>
                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c">
                    <li id="listitem">Swipe Right to view Page 1</li>
                </ul>
                </p>
            </div>
                 <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Footer content</h4>
    </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

try to send the 'footer' div to down with :

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
```

Comment: Thanks @cleondz but i have already tried this and problem still persists.

Comment: Tell us what platform is causing you this problem? Cleondz answer is a good one, it should work on all desktop browsers and most of mobile ones.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but as the web-app I am adapting is very dynamic and had no 'footer' div, I couldn't use the solution presented by cleondz.

I've found that in my case I had to use a work-around and just disable scrolling if the scrolling wasn't really necessary.

I used [this link](http://networkprogramming.wordpress.com/2012/11/13/selectively-prevent-vertical-scrolling-in-phonegap-app/) to achieve it.

```
function isDraggablePage(e)
{
    if($(‘.ui-page-active’).attr(‘draggable’)==”true”)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


function setDraggableProperty(e)
{
    if (!isDraggablePage(e))
    {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}

window.addEventListener(‘touchmove’, setDraggableProperty(e), true);
```

I don't use Javascript since a few years ago --I'm an Android dev now--, so I'm not sure the code is fine, but it works.